How can I get rid of different sized gaps between rows in a table?
I am currently trying to make a table in Latex, but I can't seem to get rid of a huge space between the second last and last row, especially in the first column.
This is my current code:
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{leftmargin!50}}m{4.66666666666cm}|>{\columncolor{leftmargin!50}}m{4.66666666666cm}|>{\columncolor{innercolor!50}}m{4.66666666666cm}|}

\cellcolor{white} & \cellcolor{white}\textbf{Farine} &\cellcolor{white}\textbf{Sucre}\\
\hline

\cellcolor{white}10 quelques & $\approx$ 5,37g  & $\approx$ 5,05g\\

\cellcolor{white}1 quelque & $\approx$ 0,45g & $\approx$ 0,43g\\

\cellcolor{white}10 quelque chose & $\approx$ 2,0g & $\approx$ 0,87g \\

\cellcolor{white}1 quelquechose 
& $\approx$ 0,12g & $\approx$ 0,07g




\end{tabular} 

Thank you in advance!

Your code snippet compiles to this, which doesn't seem to have an issue with spacing. Can you update your code snippet into a minimal example with all the necessary loaded packages so it replicates your problem? Your code should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}. Can you do that?

Off-topic: Do you think that there's a typographically meaningful difference between 4.66666666666cm and, say, 4.67cm?

I think you only have some useless blank lines in your code, get rid of them.
Also, why you set a color for the first colmun if then all its cells have \cellcolor{white}?
This compile fine (your MWE doesn't have a preamble, I invented it):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{leftmargin}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{innercolor}{gray}{0.3}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{m{4.66666666666cm}|>{\columncolor{leftmargin!50}}m{4.66666666666cm}|>{\columncolor{innercolor!50}}m{4.66666666666cm}|}
& \cellcolor{white}\textbf{Farine} &\cellcolor{white}\textbf{Sucre}\\
\hline
10 quelques & $\approx$ 5,37g  & $\approx$ 5,05g\\
1 quelque & $\approx$ 0,45g & $\approx$ 0,43g\\
10 quelque chose & $\approx$ 2,0g & $\approx$ 0,87g \\
1 quelquechose 
& $\approx$ 0,12g & $\approx$ 0,07g
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


I also suggest a solution with tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{leftmargin}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{innercolor}{gray}{0.3}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={*3X},
    column{2}={leftmargin!50},
    column{3}={innercolor!50},
    row{1}={bg=white,font=\bfseries},
    hline{2}={solid},
    vline{2,Z}={solid},
    }
    & Farine & Sucre\\
    10 quelques & $\approx$ 5,37g  & $\approx$ 5,05g\\
    1 quelque & $\approx$ 0,45g & $\approx$ 0,43g\\
    10 quelque chose & $\approx$ 2,0g & $\approx$ 0,87g \\
    1 quelquechose 
    & $\approx$ 0,12g & $\approx$ 0,07g
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



Thanks! I'm honestly lost with LaTeX, I have one table that works fine for me, but I struggle to copy it every time somehow. I'm new to this as well, so I don't have a big clue
